# How do I avoid creating Swing elements within a main method?

Tags: java, swing, static

Currently my code will not run because I have no main, but when I make a main it must be static, and I am under the impression I shouldn't be making all of my variables for the Swing elements Static, as per the advice of many.
I'm not sure how to invoke the methods without using main as the constructor, currently my gui does not appear.

Thanks.

```
 package movieinfo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Swinggui {
    JButton enter;
    public JTextField movietext;

    JList listofmovies;// converts moviestowatch into gui
    // element.
    File textfilemovie; // file which movies marked for watching
    // are saved
    java.util.List<String> moviestowatch; // arraylist which is
    // populated by
    // textfilemovie
    // than printed to
    // GUI element
    ListSelectionListener setSearch;
    JButton add;
    String info;

    public Swinggui() throws IOException {
        yourMovies();
        gui();
        jsonAndButtons();

    }

    public void gui() {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        maingui.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        enter = new JButton("Get Info");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(enter, c);
        add = new JButton("add");
        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 6;
        maingui.add(add, c);
        JTextArea movieinfo = new JTextArea(info, 5, 20);
        movieinfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2,
                Color.red));
        movietext = new JTextField(18);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(movietext, c);
        final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        maingui.add(scrolll, c);
        final JLabel titlee = new JLabel("Enter movie name below!");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        maingui.add(titlee, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        maingui.add(titlee, c);
        final JLabel watchlist = new JLabel("Watchlist");
        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(watchlist, c);
        maingui.setResizable(false);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        listofmovies = new JList(moviestowatch.toArray());
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 3;
        maingui.add(new JScrollPane(listofmovies), c);
        movieinfo.setLineWrap(true);
        movieinfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        movieinfo.setEditable(false);
        scrolll.getPreferredSize();
        listofmovies.addListSelectionListener(setSearch);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();

    }

    public void jsonAndButtons() {
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println(apicall.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()
                        .replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
                info = apicall.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText().replaceAll(" ",
                        "%20"));
            }

        });
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(
                            org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory()
                                    + "/yourmovies.txt"),
                            "\n" + movietext.getText(), true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    moviestowatch = FileUtils.readLines(textfilemovie);
                    listofmovies = new JList(moviestowatch.toArray());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

    }

    public void yourMovies() throws IOException {
        textfilemovie = new File(
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory()
                        + "/yourmovies.txt");
        textfilemovie.createNewFile();
        moviestowatch = FileUtils.readLines(textfilemovie);
        setSearch = new ListSelectionListener() {

            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                info = apicall.getMovieInfo(((String) listofmovies
                        .getSelectedValue()).replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: "*without using main as the constructor*" - How did you intend to use `main` as a constructor?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think he meant creating swing elements from inside main

Comment: Better to put Swing GUI coding aside for a bit and go through a basic Java tutorial and/or textbook. This has been recommended to you in the past, and it will only improve your GUI coding once/if you can gain an understanding of Java basics. Up to you.

Comment: `as per the advice of many.` - This is annoying!!! My suggestion to you was to use the `LabelDemo` from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Labels`. The example code shows you exactly how to do this. The code you posted here looks nothing like the code from the tutorial. We cannot spoon feed you code all the time and you need to be able to read our suggestions and follow up on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't keep everything in one class. Create some other class and then create object of that type, and invoke its methods, it would look like this in your `main()` method:

```
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
 myClass.doStuff();
```

Answer (score 2):

inside your main put:

```
new Swinggui();
```

This will pull you out of the static context and bring you into the non-static Swinggui constructor

Answer (score 0):

Make your class Swinggui extend JFrame.
Then create a main method and create object of Swinggui

```
Swinggui gui = new Swinggui();
```

now you must make gui visible, for this write.

```
gui.setVisible(true);
```

And you are good to go.

Refer everything in code using "this" and you would have non static items.

Comment: Why recommend that the class "must extend JFrame". This is patently untrue and in fact usually not recommended by most Swing experts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I like extending JFrame, that's just me. `Your class Swinggui must extend JFrame` is more than misleading though.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I read the official oracle's documentation just now, in each example they extend JPanel and create object of JFrame in main and use "frame.add(panel)". Is this the recommended approach. If not could you point me to a link or any source.
Thanks in advance